# Regex expression for Serial Number validation

Tags: regex, oracle, validation

I need to write a regex for a serial number validation.
Serial Number can be of two types

1. `AA.BB.CCC` where A,B and C are digits from 0 to 9
2. `AA.BB.CC.DDD.EEE.FF.GGGH` where A,B,C,D,E,F and G are digits and H is a character, also `AA.BB.CC.DDD`,`AA.BB.CC.DDD.EEE`,`AA.BB.CC.DDD.EEE.FF` and `AA.BB.CC.DDD.EEE.FF.GGG` 
   are valid too.

Example:
`01.01.001 - valid
 01.01.01.001 - valid
 01.01.01.001.001 - valid
 01.01.01.001.001.01 -valid
 01.01.01.001.001.01.001 -valid
 01.01.01.001.001.01.001a -valid`

`01.01.01.001.01 - invalid
 01.01.01.001.001a -invalid
 01.01.01.001.01.001 -invalid
 01.01.01.001.01.001a -invalid
 01.01.01.001.001.001 - invalid
 01.01.01.001.001.001a - invalid`

Currently I use two regexps
`'(\d{2}\.){3}\d{3}((\.\d{3})((\.\d{2})(\.\d{3}(\w)?)?)?)?$'`
and
`'(\d{2}\.){2}\d{3}$'`

Is there any way to combine this two in one?

Comment: yes, with the `|` character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can really join the two regexes with a [**`|` alternation operator**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), but you also need to [**group**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) them accordingly:

```
^((\d{2}\.){3}\d{3}((\.\d{3})((\.\d{2})(\.\d{3}(\w)?)?)?)?|(\d{2}\.){2}\d{3})$
^^                                                        ^^                ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lD4sW5/2). Do not forget about the `^`/`$` anchors to make sure the entire string meets the pattern.

Comment: did not work for me probably oracles regexp_like does not understand grouping, This works `^(((\d{2}\.){3}\d{3}((\.\d{3})((\.\d{2})(\.\d{3}(\w)?)?)?)?)|((\d{2}\.){2}\d{3}))$`

Comment: It is true, Oracle does not "know" non-capturing groups, they all must be replaced with non-capturing. You should tag the regex related questions with the language used.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in a single regular expression:

```
^\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d(\d|\.\d{3}(\.\d{3}(\.\d\d(\.\d{3}[A-H]?)?)?)?)$
```

Then you can always extract the capture groups to get the serial number components:

```
CREATE TABLE serial_numbers ( serial_number ) AS
SELECT '01.02.03'                 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '01.02.003'                FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '01.02.03.004'             FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '01.02.03.004.005'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '01.02.03.004.005.06'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '01.02.03.004.005.06.007'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '01.02.03.004.005.06.007A' FROM DUAL;

SELECT serial_number,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( serial_number, '^(\d\d)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) AS AA,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( serial_number, '^\d\d\.(\d\d)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) AS BB,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( serial_number, '^\d\d\.\d\d\.(\d\d\d?)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) AS CCC,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( serial_number, '^\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\.(\d{3})', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) AS DDD,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( serial_number, '^\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{3}\.(\d{3})', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) AS EEE,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( serial_number, '^\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\.(\d\d)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) AS FF,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( serial_number, '^\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d\d\.(\d{3})', 1, 1, NULL,  1 ) AS GGG,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( serial_number, '^\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d\d\.\d{3}([A-H])', 1, 1, NULL,  1 ) AS H
FROM   serial_numbers
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( serial_number, '^\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d(\d|\.\d{3}(\.\d{3}(\.\d\d(\.\d{3}[A-H]?)?)?)?)$' );
```

**Outputs**:

```
SERIAL_NUMBER            AA BB CCC DDD EEE FF GGG H
------------------------ -- -- --- --- --- -- --- -
01.02.003                01 02 003                  
01.02.03.004             01 02 03  004              
01.02.03.004.005         01 02 03  004 005          
01.02.03.004.005.06      01 02 03  004 005 06       
01.02.03.004.005.06.007  01 02 03  004 005 06 007   
01.02.03.004.005.06.007A 01 02 03  004 005 06 007 A
```